# Different way to optimize for loop with openmp

Tags: c++, optimization, openmp

I try to optimize a loop as much as possible, without optimization the loop looks like this:

```
typedef typename std::make_unsigned< TEMPLATE >::type unsignedType;
unsignedType *pDest = ...;
auto pSrc = function();

for(int i = 0; i < size ; ++i)
        {
            pDest[i] = static_cast< unsignedType >(pSrc[i] + 1200);
        }
```

I optimize the loop with omp parallel:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(pDest, pSrc)
for(int i = 0; i < size ; ++i)
        {
            pDest[i] = static_cast< unsignedType >(pSrc[i] + 1200);
        }
```

It is 10% more faster !

I try it to optimize it with memcpy and by avoiding conversion (so I changed the type of pSrc) but it is slower. I only gains 5%

```
memcpy(pDest, pSrc, size * sizeof(unsignedType) );
```

are there ways to optimize even more with omp or other methods?

Comment: If your task is only to copy memory between two buffers, I wouldn't think OpenMP make this any faster than a single call to `memcpy` (though benchmarking would need to be performed). In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if it's slower because you will be constantly changing from one thread to another which isn't free. Your percentages are interesting, but what is the raw time? Is it seconds, minutes? Did you compile in release? What compilation flags did you use for testing?

Comment: It is in mini secondes ! I compile with release. Memcpy is faster for a small size but when the size is really big then omp parallel is faster !

Comment: In some range of sizes and number of cores parallelization would take advantage of splitting across multiple cache and optimizing page crossing

Comment: Memcpy would normally not use internal parallelization as the overhead would be too high on small moves. You may find implementation which does that in libraries such as MKL(different function name, macro or inline function substitution possible)

Comment: Memmove may be significantly faster than memcpy. With omp 5 you could use nontemporal qualifier.